# I want to use Windows 8 from within Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, virtualization

I have Windows 8 CD.

I bought a laptop which has a Windows 7 OS but I removed it to use Ubuntu 12.04 but for some of the programs I need Windows 8 without separate partitions.

I heard about VMware and how it can help to run the OS inside another. As I have only allocated 50GB for Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, which I am using right now, I want to use Windows 8 from within my Ubuntu 12.04.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try VirtualBox. I have used Windows 7 on [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

[Installing Win 8 on virtual box](http://betanews.com/2012/03/01/install-windows-8-on-oracle-virtual-box/)

[Another link](http://www.sysprobs.com/install-windows-8-release-preview-on-virtualbox-working-guest-additions-tools)

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: how to use virtual box in ubuntu 12.04 or should i download it

Comment: @sushill Yes. You can download it from their website. If this answer helps you or any other answer in the future, please upvote it and mark the "tick".

Comment: i just download virtualbox. i am new to ubuntu os so can you help me on installing this file and telling me the process so that i can install others files next time too. i have install java but don't know what code i have written to install it. i just search for help and copy the code as per my system

Comment: @sushill I am sorry but I am really occupied right now with my PhD dissertation. However, you should read the links that I put in my answer as they will help. Google will have to be your best friend for now. Good luck. Let us know how it goes.